# How to sample image tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have one image data tensor with shape of `B*H*W*C` and one position tensor with shape of `B*H*W*2`. The values in position tensor are pixel coordinates and I want to sample pixels in image data tensor according to these pixel coordinates. I have tried one way to do that like reshaping the tensor to one-dimension tensor, but I think it's really inconvenient. I wonder whether I could implement it by some more convenient approach like matrix mapping(e.g. remap in opencv).

Answer (score 0):

I would first ask if you are sure the position matrix isn't redundant. If the position matrix entries simply correspond to the pixel locations in the image array, then for a given application however you access the position matrix could be used instead on the image data.

Perhaps as a starting point, running

```py
sess = tf.Session()
np_img, np_pos = sess.run([tf_img, tf_pos], feed_dict={...})
```

will convert tensors to numpy arrays, which may make your operations easier.
Otherwise, a 1D-tensor isn't that bad and there are TF functions for reshaping easily.